# How to check if a constraint already exists inside a view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm using auto layout for my tableView and for every cell in it, I create some constraints programmatically.

In order to avoid to delete ALL the constraints every time, I would like to know if there is a way to loop `view.constraints()` and if there is a constraint such as `H:|-view-|`, I delete it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there is some better solution for your problem without the need to check if the constraint exists.

Comment: There was some constraints that was actually added by the Auto resizing Mask but indeed I found another way.

Comment: @Nico you can give identifier to each any every constraint by that you can get the particular constraint when you want it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526879-identifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use variables (or an array) to hold those constraints that match what you want and then loop the view.constraints() to remove them. When you use the visual format, whatever you create is converted into multiple constraints.

Another method to use is to go through the constraints and check the constraint properties such as firstItem and secondItem, relation, etc. to match what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I checked if a control already have a width or height constraint (Swift 5.1):

```
debugPrint(btn.constraints.contains(where: { (item) -> Bool in
    return item.firstAttribute.rawValue == NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width.rawValue;
    }))
debugPrint(btn.constraints.contains(where: { (item) -> Bool in
    return item.firstAttribute.rawValue == NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height.rawValue;
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop the constraints. This should work:

```
toRemove = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-view-|",
                                                       options: [],
                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                         views: ["view": yourView])
viewWithConstraints.removeConstraints(toRemove)
```